# How to open "external link" by clicking a menu item?

Tags: qt, menu, external-links

I need to open some link (in my default browser) in a way similar to `setOpenExternalLink` on Qlabel, but by clicking on an item in the menu.

Is there some simple way?
I think about using Qlabel with required link and use some action/event to pretend the click on it, meanwile the Qlabel was hidden.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upon clicking the specific menu item (handled using your standard signals and slots) you could use [`openUrl(const QUrl &url)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl) of [QDesktopServices](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QDesktopServices.html) to have that link launch in your default browser.

As the documentation states, it will open

> ...the given url in the appropriate Web browser for the user's desktop environment, and returns true if successful; otherwise returns false.

So no need for fancy tricks with QLabels and the like.